# FOREACH and UPDATE mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, yii, sql-update

I have a select query followed by a an update query inside a foreach loop.

I can get the data from the select and I use it as json to draw a chart, but for the other table that should be updated with the same data from select, the specified filed  become 0 sometimes 1 or 2 !!
I tried to use a select for update and it OK (update .... (select ....)) but inside foreach it doesn't work. 
I tried also to use other columns but the same result, always I get 0. 
Any idea please ?
Many thanks in advance

this is my code

```
public function actionGetSensorsDataLive($beamId) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"');
    $sensorsIds = Sensor::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT sensor_id FROM sensor where 
                             node_id="' . $beamId . '" and sensor_name = "I" ;');

    foreach ($sensorsIds as $s) {
        $sResult = array();
       $modelSensor = SensorInfo2::model()->findBySql('SELECT * FROM information_sensor  
             where sensor_id= "' . $s['sensor_id'] . '"');

        $sResult = array(($modelSensor->information_sensor_time),
            ($modelSensor->information_sensor_value));
        /////////////// update//////////////// 
        // for every information_sensor_time that I get from the previous query  
         //  I want
        //  to update a row in another table //

        foreach ($modelSensor as $up) {
            $connection = yii::app()->db;

            $sql = 'UPDATE last_point  SET last_point_time = "' . 
                             $up['information_sensor_time'] . '"
            WHERE sensor_id= "' . $s['sensor_id'] . '"  ';

            $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
            $command->execute();
        }
        /////update end///////               
    }
    echo json_encode($sResult);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Comment: If the SQL is simple you should consider using Query Builder, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder and not inserting parameters directly.

Comment: thanks Alex, I still have the same problem. I think my problem is in foreach loop, and how to merge the update and the select together without using the loop, since I have only one record. Any idea please ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sensorsIds=Sensor::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT sensor_id FROM lead where 
                         node_id="'.$beamId.'" and sensor_name = "I" ;' );
```

Remove `;`

```
 $sensorsIds=Sensor::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT sensor_id FROM lead where 
                         node_id="'.$beamId.'" and sensor_name = "I"' );
```

Now try this.

Comment: thank you devang, is the same problem , the first part of my code there is no problem (since I get the data and I can draw it), the issue is in the update statement with foreach

Answer (score 0):

You are using findBySql()` which only returns one record and then doing a foreach on tha makes no sense. so cheng the line

```
 $modelSensor = SensorInfo2::model()->findBySql('SELECT * FROM information_sensor  
             where sensor_id= "' . $s['sensor_id'] . '"');
```

to

```
$modelSensor = SensorInfo2::model()->findAllBySql('SELECT * FROM information_sensor  
             where sensor_id= "' . $s['sensor_id'] . '"');
```

And you shoud use querybuilder which is far secure as suggested by Alex

Comment: I think I should explain better. This is a scenario,the action "actionGetSensorsDataLive"  will be query by an ajax call to get the last entry in my table that's why I used finBysql . 
I want to keep record of the fetched point by updating another table.
like this I will modify my query to fetch the point according to this record when my table sensor_info will be update at real time.
my problem is how to do the two query select and update together 
And if I can make a select and update statement while using the output of my select query.
And if the foreach loop is right or no ? many thnaks

Comment: I didnt undastand the problem. How many points are to be updated for a single `SensorInfo2` ? is the relation is HAS_MANY?

Comment: when the call "actionGetSensorsDataLive" only the last point in my table will be fetched (findbysql) this point (x,y) I will use it draw a graph and I want to update the table last point  with the value x , after one second another ajax call will be made (my table is updated continuously) and fetch the last point in my table and so on. every time I fetch (x,y) I update the table last point with the value x .

Answer (score 0):

finally I used this code

```
foreach ($sensors as $sensor)  {
$lastPointId = 1;  
$lastPoint = LastPoint::model()->findByPk($lastPointId);
$lastPoint->last_point_info = $sensor->information_time;
if ( ! $lastPoint->save()) {
    throw new CException('Unable to save last point.');
}
}
```

Thanks for all